# How to get dynamic response based on the result of the action performed in Api.ai?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying out few examples in Api.ai console. I see there are examples where the agent responds by using the values that are extracted from the user query or from the context. But is there a way to display response that is formed using the output of the action performed?

For example -

User: Is my pizza order confirmed?

Action: check order status

Response: Yes, it's confirmed (or "No, it's not")

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use some custom webhook to do this, either integrating with a 3rd party API or will a server side call of your own to a database- in this case the webhook would take the user's ID and query if their pizza is ready or not, and this would then be passed back to API.ai.

Here is an example using a 3rd party webhook to do what you are asking:
https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-weather-webhook-sample

Comment: this one uses python, any node.js samples to refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with webhooks.

Typically, you would save the status of the order in your db, then you could have an intent that would:

1. Understand the query of your user (Is my pizza order confirmed)
2. The intent would call your webhook
3. the webhook would return the status order.
4. Api.ai would then give the answer.

When you use webhooks you need to return the `speech` response, the `displayText`, optionally the `data` that your apps need, the `contextOut` and the `source`.

I guess you would also need to have implement some context in api.ai so that you could now who is asking about the satus of the order. You would then be able to use the `sessionId`

Answer (score 0):

Matt is correct here. You must use a webhook. Unfortunately the documentation from API.AI is currently very poor. Here's a screenshot example of an incoming post request. My message function will return an object with a desired response. In this case, I am using a Telegram chat bot. If you are not using any messenger, you can drop the data key: value. FollowupEvent is also optional.

[Node.JS code with Restify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izj7C.png)

On your API.AI intent, make sure to check off Webhook. If you end getting the text response 'Broken' here, then something went wrong and you should check your error codes.

[API.AI intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnP05.png)

And lastly, under the fulfillment tab, make sure to enable the webhook and point it at the right endpoint.

Comment: Please avoid posting code as images (your first screen shot). Just indent the code by 4 spaces to produce a formated output.